# Merge OpenCV 2.4.7 with pull from Github

Tags: android, opencv

I'd like to merge pull from here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1820 with opencv 2.4.7 for Android. I understand that the Library is included in project but pull from github has to be build somehow and put into my phone as new opencv manager, am i right? Could someone help with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the sources of OpenCV, and then pull or cherry-pick those two changes on top of used branch. That is more a [git](http://www.git-scm.com/) related problem than OpenCV :)

On top of that, it looks like the change You are writing about is already merged into the main branch. If You download the sources and NOT checkout on 2.4.7 tag, You will have the slightly buggy, slightly unstable bleeding-edge version of OpenCV, with these changes.

Of course, after that You will need to build the library, but there is a good manual for that at [library's web page](http://opencv.org/quickstart.html).

As for building the Android version of OpenCV, [here is a tutorial at the official wiki](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk)

Comment: Ok. So after pull i have to create lib from that, yes? For android it should be opencv-300.jar or sth like that, yes? And next i have to do what? :P Because i'm confused. I belive that i have to update opencv manager to fix problem with native camera in Android 4.4, yes? Not the library which i use in Eclipse itself, right?

Comment: And here go my chances for free exp :P. I have no idea how do You compile android version of the library, that is a totally separate question. I think that You will need to install the version of opencv manager generated with the library, as it will contain the working code.